# Accessing textarea value in Scala.js

Tags: scala.js

I'm trying to set the value of a textarea as a simple start with Scala.js. Here's the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>The Scala.js Tutorial</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <textarea id="text" cols="75" rows="12">letters</textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./target/scala-2.13/scala-js-tutorial-fastopt.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's my Scala program:

```
package learn.creation
import org.scalajs.dom
import org.scalajs.dom.document

object LearnApp {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println(document.getElementById("text").value)
    }
}
```

When I compile, I get

```
value value is not a member of org.scalajs.dom.raw.Element
[error] did you mean valueOf?
[error]         println(document.getElementById("text").value)
[error]                                                 ^
```

This doesn't work either:

```
println(document.getElementById("text").valueOf().value)
```

I can't find any documentation on this (Scala.js's dom documentation is very limited, it's not as simple as rtfm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual to read when it comes to the DOM is mostly MDN web docs, scala-js-dom is only a very thin interface to it, with almost all methods being the same and returning the same types.

You are using the [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) method which returns a generic `Element` type that does not have a `value` property because not all elements in the DOM have such a property. And scala-js-dom [defines](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js-dom/blob/3059c5d8684a2768808bf17cd534b046b1320534/src/main/scala/org/scalajs/dom/raw/lib.scala#L3327) `getElementById` in the same way.

So essentially, you haven't proved to the compiler that the element you've selected is of a kind that has a value property, such as a [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) or [HTMLTextAreaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement). You will generally not be able to prove such things when using Javascript's native methods to query the DOM, because they are designed for dynamic Javascript, not for type safe access.

You can build your own helpers for this, such as:

```scala
def getTextareaById(id: String): HTMLTextAreaElement = {
  document.querySelector("textarea#" + id).asInstanceOf[HTMLTextAreaElement]
}
```

In this case, you use `asInstanceOf` to tell the compiler "I know what I'm doing", which is unsafe, but you also contain this unsafety inside a small method that you can reasonably understand to be safe, since it only selects elements with the tag "textarea", and you know that all of those are instances of `HTMLTextAreaElement`.

If your DOM is generated on the server this is probably the best you can do, but if you're building a single page web app where the DOM tree is created on the client you can use a Scala.js UI library that will give you a better, easier, type safe API to the DOM, such as my own [Laminar](https://laminar.dev).

Comment: [Laminar](https://laminar.dev/) is amazing. Very simple but yet powerful and concise. I highly encourage all frontend developers to take a look at it.